# application crash using just_audio_background

Tags: flutter, just-audio, audio-service

I am literally going crazy because I cannot explain what happened. I am making an application in flutter and I need to play an audio file in the background...(more like I need the notification that the audio player creates).
Until yesterday it was working perfectly. I would initialize just_audio_background, create the MediaItems as the official guide shows me, and when I would play the player the notification would appear correctly. Since today, however, on my oneplus 8t when the song is supposed to start, the app crashes with this output:

```
D/OplusScrollToTopManager(31518): com.example.yessey/com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity,This DecorView@6dbafe8[AudioServiceActivity] change focus to true
D/AndroidRuntime(31518): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(31518): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(31518): Process: com.example.yessey, PID: 31518
E/AndroidRuntime(31518): android.app.RemoteServiceException$BadForegroundServiceNotificationException: Bad notification(tag=null, id=1124) posted from package com.example.yessey, crashing app(uid=11029, pid=31518): Couldn't inflate contentViewsjava.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
```

Let me premise that I have tried the simulator integrated in android studio and everything works correctly. The most absurd thing is that if I deactivate from the application settings directly on the phone, the silent notifications category 'Audio Playback' (which can be found in the Notifications section at the bottom) everything works correctly; the notification is created and the song starts regularly. I've already tried uninstalling the app and re-installing it. I've tried checking the whole just_audio_background official guide again, but everything is correct (in fact on the simulator it works).

I'll leave you the part of the code where I initialise the package and then the part where I call the functions that interest me...

thank you very much to those who can clarify this situation for me

**inizialize in the main**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  print("Init Wakelock");
  await Wakelock.enable();

  print("Init Firebase");
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  print("Init JustAudioBackground");
  try {
    await JustAudioBackground.init(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.ryanheise.bg_demo.channel.audio',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio playback',
      androidNotificationOngoing: true,
    );
    print("JustAudioBackground OK");
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error JustAudioBackground: $e");
  }
```

**function**

```
 Future<void> initializePlayer() async {
    final audioSource = AudioSource.uri(
      Uri.parse('https://example/mute.mp3'),
      tag: MediaItem(
        id: '1',
        album: "per salvare il replay!",
        title: "Cambia volume",
        artUri: Uri.parse('https://example.png'),
      ),
    );
    await _player.setAudioSource(audioSource);
    await _player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.one);
    await _player.play();
  }
```

I would like to point out that the application crashes when I send the player to start, and not during initialisation, which takes place correctly...

i tried deleting the image, of the album, editing the mp3 file. the only thing that worked was just deactivating the silent notifications called Audio Playback. On the android studio simulator, on the other hand, it works perfectly.

Comment: I would suggest submitting a bug report with a minimal reproduction project.

Comment: Did you create a bug report? What device and Android version are you on?

Comment: I am unable to make a bug report. But I can respond here. i own oneplus 8t with oxygenOS 13.1. 
And exactly what I wrote above happens. Tell me how I can send you a video where you can see the abnormal behavior(if needed).

Comment: Ryan, I sent you a video in your email showing the problem

Comment: Please don't send me private emails, as written in the instructions bug reports should be sent to GitHub. The sooner you do this, the sooner I can help you to try out a solution.